# Efficiently exporting floating-point numbers to a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, optimization, compression

For precomputation purposes I need to store a large number (tens of millions) of single-precision floating point numbers in a comma-separated file.

My performance priorities are, in this order:

1. Reading speed
2. File size
3. Writing speed

Right now I am just writing the string representations of the numbers, which can obviously be improved upon. What would be some good ways to accomplish this?

Comment: CSV files are _text-based_ files by definition. the string representation is the only valid form; _please_ don't store binary data in CSV files. you might want to look into BSON, if it doesn't have to be CSV. but maybe your best solution is to simply _write the binary data_ as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and most efficient solution (file size) is storing binary data in binary format. In rough lines (not optimized in any way):

```
private static IEnumerable<float> read()
{
    using (var file = new FileStream(//whatever)
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
    {
        while (file.Position < file.Length)
            yield return reader.ReadSingle();
    }
}

private static void write(IEnumerable<float> ff)
{
    using (var file = new FileStream(//whatever)
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
        foreach (var f in ff)
            writer.Write(f);
    }
}
```

If you need to keep a csv format then there really isn't any option around writing and reading text representations of the floats, which makes the process considerably slower and the file size can be orders of magnitude larger.

Answer (score 1):

For your #2 objective, you need to know what parts of your numbers actually matter, and are there correlations. Are they constrained in range? What is the accuracy with which they were measured? Do all six digits matter? Is this a time sequence with small differences between successive numbers?

That information can be used to compress the sequence of floating-point values. Limit them the range and precision that value represent. You can take the difference between successive values and send just those (except for the first one), if there is correlation. Or you could have a more complex model to predict the next number given the sequence the precedes it, and send the difference between the actual and predicted for each number.

Then you can try compressing the result of that with a standard lossless compressor, such as gzip, zlib, zstd, lz4, etc.

That all results in a compact binary file. If you really need the result to be a readable .csv, you could still constrain the precision and do difference coding, to provide some compression. The difference coding would then need to be undone on the other end.